# Auto layout multiple lines label in UITableview // Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4.2

I wrote such extension to display my data in UITableview. But sometimes my data can contain more than 1 line and I need to create something to display full content. How could I change my code (below) to do it?

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Define no of rows in your tableView
    func tableView(_ chatHistoryTable: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messagesData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ chatHistoryTable: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = chatHistoryTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userMessage")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = messagesData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .right

        return cell;
    }

}
```

I think that I should write something for UITableViewCell too, but I don't know, am I correct.

Please help me with this question.

Comment: Take a look at this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/6057764)

Comment: @vpoltave here labels are not creating by code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in here you need to follow two changes.

- initially set the estimate height and auntomaticdimension for [Self Sizing Cell](https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/), on your page loads call the following line.

  ```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
  ```

  for e.g

  ```
   @IBOutlet weak var yourTableviewName: UITableView!{
  didSet{
      yourTableviewName.tableFooterView = UIView()
      yourTableviewName.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
     yourTableviewName.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
      }
    }
  ```
- secondary for your word wrap and numberOfLines for your lables.  follow the below line on your cellforRow  method

  ```
     func tableView(_ chatHistoryTable: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = chatHistoryTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userMessage")! as UITableViewCell
       cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
      cell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
      cell.textLabel!.text = messagesData[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .right

      return cell;
  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1. Add a chain of unbroken vertical constraints in Custom Table View Cell

Step 2. Set the cell estimated height

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Step 3:Make the label support multiple lines

```
textLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
textLabel.Lines = 0;
```